# Invisible checkbox (same color as background) in a VSTO PPT Addin's ribbon

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto, ribbon

I'm building a C# VSTO plugin using Visual Studio Ribbon designer for the UI.

I am trying to add a checkbox inside a menu which seems like a straightforward use case.

However:

- The checkbox is white without border by default in Office365...
- ... and the menu background is white by default in Office365 (－‸ლ)
- Outside of a menu, the ribbon is slightly dark white, hence the checkbox is normally visible there

It doesn't seem like there is any option to change the color of the checkbox or the menu background either programmatically or through the Ribbon Designer.

Did anyone every encounter this issue, if yes any creative idea to resolve this?

The menu in the Ribbon Designer:
[image: screenshot]

The menu in the live app: [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The Fluent UI (nor VSTO) doesn't provide anything for changing colors on the ribbon.

You can read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#officemenu)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)